# How to add an SKNode to an SKScene

Tags: objective-c, oop, sprite-kit, sknode

When I enter this line in `initWithSize:Size`

```
[self addChild:world];
```

I retrive an error `Thread 1:signal SIGABRT`

- `world` is an SKNode
- The children that should be in `world` are also SKNode's

What am I doing wrong here as when I add the SKNode to the scene I retrieve an error

`initWithSize:Size` Method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{

if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){

        //self.size = CGSizeMake(2048, 1048);
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        _character = [self createCharacter];
        [self addChild:_character];
        [self addChild:world];
        [self createChunks];
        [world addChild:_character];
        NSLog(@"Children in world: %@",[world children]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

`createChunks:` Method:

```
-(void)createChunks{

    ProceduralMapGeneration *procedure = [[ProceduralMapGeneration alloc]init];
    [procedure allocArrays];

    _chunkOne = [procedure createChunk];
    _chunkOne.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2, self.scene.size.height/2);
    [world addChild:_chunkOne];

    _chunkTwo = [procedure createChunk];
    _chunkTwo.position = CGPointMake(400,200);
    [world addChild:_chunkTwo];
}
```

create chunks adds the chunks to `world`

---

`world` is created here

```
@implementation MainGame{

    SKNode *world;
    SKSpriteNode *_character;
    SKNode *_chunkOne;
    SKNode *_chunkTwo;
    ProceduralMapGeneration *categoryBitManager;
}
```

## Stack Trace

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x019161e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016958e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01915fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   SpriteKit                           0x0117cfca -[SKNode addChild:] + 175
    4   Giraffe Rampage                     0x0000289d -[MainGame initWithSize:] + 413
    5   SpriteKit                           0x0115ca09 +[SKScene sceneWithSize:] + 104
    6   Giraffe Rampage                     0x0000555d -[MainMenu touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 429
    7   SpriteKit                           0x0116e2bf -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 824
    8   UIKit                               0x00274c0b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x002759d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    10  UIKit                               0x002475f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    11  UIKit                               0x00231353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0189f77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0189f10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x018bc1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x018bb9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x018bb7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0390a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0390a42b GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x00233f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  Giraffe Rampage                     0x00005e6d main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x01f5d701 start + 1
) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire method implementation ?

Comment: @giorashc it has been updated

Comment: Where the world object is created and how ? do you get a stack trace for the signal abort ? (Check the threads stack view in xcode if possible)

Comment: init world object ,before adding it to scene, like this world = [SKNode node];

Comment: @giorashc updated with stack trace and where world is created

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir even if i enter the init method it still crashes

Comment: First you add character to self and then you add it to world. This could be causing the exception

Comment: Not just could, that's the issue. You'll find in the log a message that says something along the lines of "xxx already has a parent".

Answer (score 0):

```
[self addChild:_character];
...
[world addChild:_character];
```

You added _character twice.